# Techniques for bypassing zero length check in javascript?

Tags: authentication, javascript, node.js

I am working on a node.js application that allows users to sign up for accounts using social media.  When they do this an entry is created in our database with their email address, and a blank password.

When I saw this I became concerned that someone could simply supply an email address and a blank password to log in as anyone who had a social media account.  After some quick testing it appears that there is a line in the authentication code that throws an error if there is a zero length password.  The line is below:

```
 if (!username || !password) { ...
```

The only thing that I could think of to try and trip this up was to pass a URL encoded DEL character in (`%7F`) but this didn't bypass either.

I'm just curious if I am safe with the above or if there is some character that could be passed in that would get past the check above?

Comment: Is this the client-side JavaScript that is doing the password length checking?

Comment: No this is Node.JS which is server side javascript. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test you have:

```
if (!username || !password)
```

Checks if either `username` and `password` values are javascript falsey values.  A falsey value in javascript is any one of these : `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN` or an empty string.

An empty string in javascript is a zero length string so if it has at least one character in it (any character will suffice), then it is not an empty string.

---

So, if because of the way your code is structured, you know that both `username` and `password` will always be strings, then the above code is just checking to see if either of them are empty strings.

There is no character that could be in those strings that would pass the above test.  One of the strings must be completely empty (zero length) to pass that test.